# Adding A Div For Every 4th MySQL Result With Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a script that displays images from a database.
Every 4 pictures is contained in a `<div class="row">`.

I added a pagination script to this page to limit the number of images and I ran into a problem.

When there are 4 or 8 images on a page the script works fine, but if there are only 1 or 7 images on the page, the closing `</div>` for the `<div class="row">` doesn't get added.

This is my entire script:

```
  $conn = getConnected("lucycypher");

  $img_start=0;
  $img_limit=8;

  if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $page=$_GET['page'];
   $img_start=($page-1)*$img_limit;
  }
  else { $page = 1; }

  $img_total=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "select * from gallery_img"));
  $img_total_count=ceil($img_total/$img_limit);

  echo '<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
         <ul class="pagination">'  . PHP_EOL;
  if($page>1) {
  echo '<li><a href="?page='.($page-1).'" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">Previous</span></a></li>'  . PHP_EOL;
  }
  for($i=1;$i<=$img_total_count;$i++) {
   if($i==$page) { echo "<li class='active'><a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"  . PHP_EOL; }
   else { echo "<li><a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"  . PHP_EOL; }
  }
  if($page!=$img_total_count) {
   if(!isset($page)) { echo '<li><a href="?page='.($page+2).'" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">Next</span></a></li>'  . PHP_EOL; }
   else { echo '<li><a href="?page='.($page+1).'" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">Next</span></a></li>'  . PHP_EOL; }
  }

echo '</ul>
      </nav>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
 </div>
  </div>
<?php
  if($_COOKIE['age_verification'] == "adult") {
   $img_query = "SELECT img_name, img_category, img_location FROM gallery_img order by img_time desc LIMIT $img_start, $img_limit;";
  }
  else if($_COOKIE['age_verification'] == "child") {
   $img_query = "SELECT img_name, img_category, img_location FROM gallery_img WHERE img_category NOT LIKE '%nude' order by img_time desc LIMIT $img_start, $img_limit;";
  }
  $img_result = mysqli_query($conn, $img_query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($img_result) > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      $img_count = 1;
      while($img_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($img_result)) {
       $tags = $img_row["img_category"]; 
          if ( $img_count%4 === 1 ) { echo '<div class="row">' . PHP_EOL; } // Create new row for every 4th image
          echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . PHP_EOL;
          echo '<div class="panel panel-default">' . PHP_EOL;
          echo '<img src="http://lucycypher.com/h/400/w/300/a/c/thumb/'.$img_row["img_location"].'" class="img-responsive img-protected">' . PHP_EOL;
          echo '<div class="panel-footer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> Tags: ' . $tags . '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
          echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
          echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
          if ( $img_count%4 === 0 ) { echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL; } // Close row
          $img_count++;
      }
  } else {
          echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . PHP_EOL;
          echo '<div class="panel panel-primary">' . PHP_EOL;
          echo '<div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Sorry</div>' . PHP_EOL;
          echo 'No recent uploads.' . PHP_EOL;
          echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
          echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
  }
  ?>

   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <?php
  echo '<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
         <ul class="pagination">'  . PHP_EOL;
  if($page>1) {
  echo '<li><a href="?page='.($page-1).'" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">Previous</span></a></li>'  . PHP_EOL;
  }
  for($i=1;$i<=$img_total_count;$i++) {
   if($i==$page) { echo "<li class='active'><a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"  . PHP_EOL; }
   else { echo "<li><a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"  . PHP_EOL; }
  }
  if($page!=$img_total_count) {
   if(!isset($page)) { echo '<li><a href="?page='.($page+2).'" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">Next</span></a></li>'  . PHP_EOL; }
   else { echo '<li><a href="?page='.($page+1).'" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">Next</span></a></li>'  . PHP_EOL; }
  }

echo '</ul>
      </nav>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Once I figure this out I'm going to limit the images to 8 per page so on the last page if there are only 3 total images then it's missing the final `</div>` tag since there isn't a total of 4 which completely throws off the rest of the page layout.

Best way to explain it is a visual I assume:

When images total 4 per row with a limit of 8:

```
<div class="row">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
</div>
<div class="row">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
</div>
```

But if the final page only has 3 images:

```
<div class="row">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
 <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
<!--Missing </div> Tag-->
```

The final `</div>` tag is set by this line: `if ( $img_count%4 === 0 ) { echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL; } // Close row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may calculate the total count of images, which will be uploaded.

Then, use `if ( $img_count%4 === 0 || $img_count==$total_count )`

In my example `$img_count` is the number of added image (beginning from 1)

Comment: `$img_count` is used for counting how many total images there are in the database table.

Comment: Did you calculate the total count correctly? Look. If you have 7 images, then after the 7th ( as 7 == 7 ) the </div> will be added. Id it didn't- then you did it wrong

Comment: $img_count is total count?? Are you sure? Then if ( $img_count%4 === 0 ) looks very strange

Comment: Whoops I confused it with a different variable.

Comment: Added explanation to my answer. Be attentive

Comment: I don't have a variable for `$total_count` in my script.

Comment: Then add it. Is it your script?

Comment: It is my script. I don't understand how I would count the remaining images in this situation though to get the total.

Comment: You don't need to count the remaining. You count the total number in the beginning. It's one simple SQL query

Comment: I wasn't understanding earlier but now I do and it worked. Thanks. I simply made that line: `if ( $img_count%4 === 0 || $img_count == mysqli_num_rows($img_result) ) { echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL; } // Close row` And it works perfectly.